# Firebase Google Login for two clients

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I need to login to the same firebase app using android client and web client. How can I do that?

From documentation,I understand we need to create android type google OAuth Client ID and for web client we need to create Web Applictaion Type type google OAuth Client ID. Once we create these two different type of IDs, I notice that in Firebase App Dashboard - Login And Auth Screen for Google, we can mention only one key.

How can I handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using authWithOAuthToken method solved the problem for the web client.

```
ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", "<ACCESS-TOKEN>", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```